# want to download file from google drive picker

Tags: angularjs, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I want to download files from google drive picker. I am using google drive picker and select file. it return me these parameters

https://github.com/softmonkeyjapan/angular-google-picker

```
$$hashKey : "009"
description :   ""
embedUrl :  "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bz9ps73AlkCwZkp6RzNaSWhCbEU&export=download"
iconUrl     :"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_12_pdf_list.png"
id :    "0B32ps73232wZk3236RzNaSWhCbEU"
lastEditedUtc : 14873223312734
mimeType :  "application/pdf"
name:   "ABCs.pdf"
parentId :  "0AD93223AlkC32O789A"
serviceId : "DoclistBlob"
sizeBytes: 13754
type:   "file"
url:    "https://docs.google.com/document/d/KVASPSyy4f7gRurmm8W7YqKh-Lqb_Rc/edit?usp=drive_web"
```

I have read, I need oAuthToken fileId but didn't get oAuthToken and fileId. Please let me know where can i  get this ?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#appreg), your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token when creating a `Picker` object with views that accesses private user data. You may refer with this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176112/5832311) wherein it stated that:

- You can get `oAuthToken` from JS client side when user authenticates.

> If you use the example from [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/), the function looks like this:
>
> ```
> function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
>     if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
>         oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
>         oauthToken; // <-- THIS IS THE Bearer token
>         createPicker();
>         }
> }
> ```

- You can get `fileId` when user picks a file.

> A modified example from Google docs.
>
> ```
> function pickerCallback(data) {
>     if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
>         var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
>         alert('You picked fileId: ' + doc[google.picker.Document.ID]);
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am geting access_token  and file id but i am unable to download file from google drive :(